# Get user ID/name in script bounded to Google Sites

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

I am trying to make a Google Apps Script bounded to Google Sites using a regular Gmail account that allows users to upload files to a central Drive. I can do this, but the problem I an struggling with is identifying who uploaded the file.

If I make their name an input that works fine, I run the script as 'me' and the files go on my Drive. However, asking the user to enter their own name is a) prone to error and variation, and b) unnecessary as they should already be logged in.

So, if I use `getActiveUser` to retrieve their ID nothing is returned as the script is running as 'me'. (`getEffectiveUser` is ok but always returns my ID).

Is there any way I can find the actual users ID in a script running as 'me'.?

Alternatively, the users could upload their files to their own Drive and share them with me. Is that possible through scripting?  (Less favoured option, in that they could change the file, making a kind of 'moving target')

Comment: Are you using a domain or a normal Gmail account?

Comment: Thanks for looking at my query. I am using regular gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible if you published to "run as me". In that case getActiveUser returns an email only if its from the same (multi)domain as you (google apps only).
Else loke your case returns null.
Your only option is to publish to 'run as user' but that means it will save it in their drive not yours.

Comment: Thanks for that. It was as I suspected but wasn't sure.